# System.UnauthorizedAccessException has been thrown: Reading from JSON file

Tags: c#, json, file, serialization

I am trying to read a JSON file stored on my PC and then deserialize it using Json.Net to store into an object. 
However when I try to read from it, I keep getting an 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException has been thrown. Access to the path '/Users/person/JsonFolder' is denied'

I have read a lot of SO posts about this same issue and I have tried running as Administrator, make sure I have administrative rights to the path, trying different ways of reading from file, you name it. I have tried it on multiple PCs with the same issue.

Am I just reading from file wrong? I feel like I am going crazy.
Any recommendations are much appreciated :)

```
public void ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        dateofFile = @GetDateOfFile(fileName); 
        string filePath = @"/Users/person/Jsonfolder";

        JsonFile json1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonFile>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));

        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            JsonFile json2 = (JsonFile)ser.Deserialize(file, typeof(JsonFile));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this in ASP.NET or from a console/desktop application?

Comment: If it is a web application, you need to set the identity for AppPool

Comment: You are reading your file correcly. however the user running the application does not have propper system rights. temporarelly add "All Users" to the desired folder with read/write access. Create a file in this folder. Look at who created the file and give that specific user Read access to the folder(and remove all users)

Comment: This is a console application @toadflakz

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was. I was referencing the FOLDER and not the file IN the folder. Thanks everyone for your help